# Can you use the cluster function twice in a cox regression in R?

Tags: r, cox-regression

So I have a cox query - so I am trying to do a cox regression and I wonder if I can cluster the data twice:

```
cox1<-coxph(formula = Surv(time.to.arrive..trap, Arrived.1.or.0) ~     
            Is.feeder.control.or.stimulus + cluster(id.location) + cluster(New.ID), 
            data = all.data)
cox1
```

- I have a data set in which I have 200 birds, I set up paired feeders (control and stimulus) in a wood in five locations one after the other. (At any one time there was only one control and one stimulus feeder out)

I am trying to work out if there is a difference of time to arrive at the control or stimulus feeder - however I want to take into account that birds can appear multiple times in my data - (at control and stimulus, either or both at each of the five locations). Does it make sense to use the cluster function twice? In the above formula I clustered it by ID of the bird and by location.Id.

This may seem like an obvious question - but has been causing me no end of trouble! Thank you very much indeed in advance for any light you can shed on the matter!!

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the specific answer to your question regarding clustering two variables within `coxph`, but perhaps you can create an interaction factor between `id.location` and `New.ID` and then cluster that variable (and calling `cluster` only once)

For example,

```
all.data$newvar <- interaction(all.data$id.location, all.data$New.ID)
cox1<-coxph(formula = Surv(time.to.arrive..trap, Arrived.1.or.0) ~     
        Is.feeder.control.or.stimulus + cluster(newvar), data = all.data)
```